# Memoize a prototype method

Tags: javascript, memoization

I'm trying to use memoization to speed up my Javascript, but I need it on a `proto` method, and I need said method to have access to the `this` object, and it's giving me fits. Here's what I have:

```
MyObj.prototype.myMethod = function(){
    var self = this
        , doGetData = (function() {
            var memo = []
            , data = function(obj) {
                var result = memo;
                if (obj.isDirty) {
                    obj.isDirty = false;
                    result = $.map(obj.details, function(elem, i) {
                        return elem.export();
                    });   
                    memo = result;                      
                }
                return result;
            }
            return data;            
        }())
    ;
    return doGetData(self);
};
```

I can get it to run, I just can't get it to memoize. I know something is wrong, but I can't figure out what. I know there are tons of examples of how to memoize, but none that I've come across deal with scope like this.

Comment: How do you know it's not working properly?

Comment: i've been doing log checks, and when `isDirty` is false, the `result` is an empty array, `[]`. `isDirty`'s initial state is `true` to force a collection of the data to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the function on the prototype, but you want it to memoize for each instance independently, then "memo" needs to be an instance property (or a closure could be the instance property, I guess; whichever).

```
MyObj.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  if (!("memo" in this) || this.isDirty) {
    this.isDirty =false;
    this.memo = $.map(obj.details, function(elem, i) {
       return elem.export();
    });
  }
  return this.memo;
};
```

I don't think you can do it without polluting the instances, though you could use newer JavaScript features to keep the "memo" thing from being enumerable. The prototype is shared by all instances, after all.

Comment: @Jason That will only work if you make sure that there's a "getData" property on every instance. You can't store the "memo" for each separate instance as the same property of the prototype object's "getData" function, unless the underlying code is such that the results are always the same for each instance anyway.

Comment: the `getData` property is the prototype function, meaning it should be on every instance. I'm referencing it by `this.getData.memo`. Shouldn't that give it a unique value per instance?

Comment: ok i cheated again.. i created a `this._cache` and stored the value there :\ would like to use memoization if i could tho to prevent pollution

Comment: @Jason Well the thing is that the only place to keep per-instance stuff is on the instance :/ You can use `Object.defineProperty` to make sure that the property doesn't show up in `for ... in` loops.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a Map object for storing and retrieving method caches for all instances. Maps support objects as keys. (Kind of off-topic, but strict mode affects the propagation of "this". Now this works without "var self = this;".)

```
"use strict";
MyObj.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    var prototypeCache = new Map();
    return function(arg) {
        if (!prototypeCache.has(this)) prototypeCache.set(this, new Map());
        var instanceCache = prototypeCache.get(this);
        if (instanceCache.has(arg)) return instanceCache.get(arg);
        else {
            //Do expensive calculation that is stored in result...
            instanceCache.set(arg, result);
            return result;
        }                
    };
}();
```

Now for simplicity I also used a Map for the instanceCache. For speed one would typically use just an object. It depends on the keys one can make. It is typically possible to find a way to store by unique strings. (Numbers can be converted, Objects can have id strings and state/version properties, multiple arguments can be concatenated into one string...)

Another solution entirely is to create the method in the constructor instead of having it in the prototype. But that is just as bad pollution as having method caches in instance properties. Much worse, I think.